# How to simplify Json Keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have Json object as follows

```
var data= {
            "10":"One",
            "11":"One",
            "12":"One",
            "13":"One",            

            "20":"Two",
            "21":"Two",
            "22":"Two",
            "23":"Two",            
        }
```

Is there any way that I can simplify like

```
var data= {
            "10-13":"One",

            "20-23":"Two",         
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how that's any simpler...

Comment: When I see code like this it makes me wonder that you could simplify this by fixing the root cause of such structure. Although I am not sure whether you just provide some dummy values. Hearing more about the problem would be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Using only the data you've provided, I'm inclined to say that your object is upside-downus, back-to-frontus.

```
var data = {
    "One" : [10,11,12,13],
    "Two" : [20,21,22,23]
};
```

But, it depends entirely on how you're using this data! In all likelihood, the structure you have now is the right one for the job. I don't know, how would I know?

Side-note: There is no such thing as a "Json object". JSON is a string that represents an object in a syntax that is compatible with JavaScript.

Comment: for ex: I want to retrieve it by data['11']--> "One"

Comment: In that case, the structure you have right now is just fine.

Comment: "in a syntax that is compatible with JavaScript." --- http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset

Comment: @zerkms "There’s a sneaky little Unicode character in there too: Right between “ro” and “cks!” there’s a tiny U+2028." Yeah... an unescaped UTF-8 character which isn't valid JSON in the first place.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol: it **IS** valid json. The `U+2028` character is a valid character for **ANY** JSON string. http://www.json.org/string.gif

Comment: Hmm... I wouldn't trust it to handle characters outside the 32-127 range, but okay then.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
var data = {
    "10-13": "One",
    "20-23": "Two"
}
var result = {};
for (range in data) {
    ends = range.split('-');
    ends.length === 1 && ends.push(ends[0]);
    for (var n = parseInt(ends[0]); n < parseInt(ends[1]) + 1; n++) {
        result[String(n)] = data[range];
    }
}
console.debug(result);
```

gives:

```
{10: "One", 11: "One", 12: "One", 13: "One", 20: "Two", 21: "Two", 22: "Two", 23: "Two"}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your favorite browser go into web developer mode and just paste in:

```
var obj={};
for(var k=startYouWant; k< lengthYouWant+startYouWant; k++){
    var ks = k.toString();
    obj[k]="one";
}
```

then do JSON.stringify(obj);

then copy that into the code you're actually working on :)

HTH